# Can REST Call to (e.g. Yahoo API, etc.) From http://localhost?

Tags: web-services, api, rest

Hi the question is self-explanatory. Can I use REST call to API which uses REST (e.g. Yahoo API, etc.)
while I'm developing in http:  //localhost ?

Past experience, I called WSDL from my http:  //localhost development successfully with internet connection, I wonder if this can also be done in REST?

The basic functions I'm calling are a recommender system which can consist of a few individual functions.

Related and specific advices would be appreciated, thanks.

Regards,
John Maxim

Comment: John, perhaps you should try this [tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-rest.html) from directly from Yahoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as your machine is allowing outbound http connections then it is no difference from using any other server.

Comment: Hi ceejayoz, by initiating the contact, do you mean sending actions/methods to the API ? thanks.

Comment: If you can connect to a WSDL resource then you should be able to call a REST interface. The transport is the same (HTTP).